# Typing Complete Graphs with edge and vertex label

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I'm new here. I think this is the right place to ask this question.

Basically I would like to type a simple looking complete graph like this:

http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Complex_network_K6_complete_graph.png

What I want is to place vertex and edge labels on top of the edges and vertices.

How would I go on doing that? What packages am I supposed to use and what commands should I type?

[image]

Sorry I should have included this picture to show what I have in mind. Thank you!

Comment: Some graph examples made with `tkz-graph` package: http://www.altermundus.com/pages/tkz/graph/index.html and http://graphtheoryinlatex.blogspot.com.es

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use TikZ and its amazing `graph` library for this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphs.standard}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \graph { subgraph K_n [n=8,clockwise,radius=2cm] };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

You can also add edge labels very easily:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphs.standard,quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \graph[circular placement, radius=4cm,
         empty nodes, nodes={circle,draw}] {
    \foreach \x in {a,...,f} {
      \foreach \y in {\x,...,f} {
        \x -- \y;
      };
    };
    a --["3"'] b;
    a --["2"' near start] c;
    a --["1", near start] e;
    a --["1",] f;
    e --["2"'] f;
  };
  \foreach \x [count=\idx from 0] in {a,...,f} {
    \pgfmathparse{90 + \idx * (360 / 6)}
    \node at (\pgfmathresult:4.4cm) {\x};
  };
  \draw (a) edge[red, thick] node[black,left,pos=.2] {1} (d);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: You could define a macro which takes a parameter of the number of nodes and then separate each of the circle with degree `360/#1`.  I was about to post a solution along those lines, but probably better if you make that minor tweak.

Comment: @PeterGrill Like I did in my edit?

Comment: One problem with your labelled edges is that some labels are over-written. The labels `1<-->4` and `2<-->5` are hiding behind `3<-->6`  (I think).

Comment: Thank you for this. How could I tweak this a bit so that it will look like that picture on my edit? Is there a way so that the edge labels and the vertex labels are outside? And how could I label them individually? Thank you!

Comment: @chowching See my edit.

Comment: This works great when you have six nodes, but if you only have five the graph isn't drawn symmetrically.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist did you adjust the pgfmathparse expression?

Comment: It's the nested for each loops that place the nodes. Changing f to e in '{a,...,f}` makes the graph asymmetric.

Answer (score 4):

Just another suggestion with PSTricks. Readability level is kept high in both code and its output.

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\degrees[6]

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
\multido{\iA=0+1,\iB=1+1}{6}{\Cnode[radius=3mm](4;\iA){N\iB}\rput(N\iB){\iB}}
\multido{\iA=1+1}{5}{%
    \multido{\iB={\numexpr\iA+1\relax}+1}{\numexpr6-\iA}{%
        \ncline[strokeopacity=.25]{N\iB}{N\iA}\ncput*[nrot=:U,npos=.8]{\scriptsize$\iA\leftrightarrow\iB$}}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `6<->ϛ` is still understandable, unless either 6 or 9 appears  twice.

Answer (score 3):

run with `xelatex`

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,multido}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
\degrees[6]
\multido{\iA=0+1,\iB=1+1}{6}{\Cnode[radius=3mm](4;\iA){N\iB}\rput(N\iB){\iB}}
\multido{\iA=1+1}{5}{%
  \multido{\iB={\numexpr\iA+1\relax}+1}{\numexpr6-\iA}{\ncline{N\iA}{N\iB}}}
\multido{\iA=1+1}{5}{%   The same for the labels
  \multido{\iB={\numexpr\iA+1\relax}+1}{\numexpr6-\iA}{%
     \ncline[linestyle=none]{N\iA}{N\iB}\ncput*[npos=0.65]{\scriptsize$\iA\leftrightarrow\iB$}}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry. `4<->6` and `5<->1` need some space to avoid overlapping each other.